# Using underscore.js to compare two Objects

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

I'm trying to compare two objects with underscore.

**Object 1 (Filter)**

```
{
  "tuxedoorsuit":"tuxedoorsuit-tuxedo",
  "occasions":"occasions-wedding"
}
```

**Object 2 (Properties)**

```
{
  "tuxedoorsuit":"tuxedoorsuit-tuxedo",
  "occasions":"occasions-wedding",
  "occasions":"occasions-prom",
  "product_fit":"product_fit-slim",
  "colorfamily":"colorfamily-black"
}
```

I want to return true when all items of Object 1 are found within Object 2.  What would be the best underscore method to use for this?

Comment: What about http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual and http://underscorejs.org/#isMatch ?

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar: You should make that an answer. It's much better than the currently accepted.

Comment: @Bergi : I agree `isMatch` would be far better. But actually it's interesting to note that it won't work in this case, because "Object 2" is malformed. It has two times the same property `occasions`. [isMatch](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-106) casts "Object 2" to a standard Object and this will only keep the last value of this property : `occasions-prom`. It will then return `false`.

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar Ah, nice :) I included `isMatch` in my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @slaur4: In fact, that the object syntax is malformed causes the *parser* to drop the "first" value (or, in strict mode, to throw a syntax error). `isMatch` is not to blame here, any other method would work the same - except when it would take object 2 as JSON and used a tolerant parser internally.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Edit:** As per [Arnaldo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632281/using-underscore-js-to-compare-two-objects/28632359#comment45564860_28632281), you can use [`isMatch`](https://underscorejs.org/#isMatch) function, like this

```
console.log(_.isMatch(object2, object1));
```

The description says,

> `_.isMatch(object, properties)`
>
> Tells you if the keys and values in **properties** are contained in **object.**

If you want to iterate yourself, just use [`_.keys`](https://underscorejs.org/#keys) and [`_.every`](https://underscorejs.org/#every), like this

```
_.every(_.keys(object1), function(currentKey) {
    return _.has(object2, currentKey) &&
        _.isEqual(object1[currentKey], object2[currentKey]);
});
```

Or the chained version,

```
var result = _.chain(object1)
    .keys()
    .every(function(currentKey) {
        return _.has(object2, currentKey) &&
            _.isEqual(object1[currentKey], object2[currentKey]);
    })
    .value();
```

If the result is `true`, it means that all the keys in `object1` are in `object2` and their values are also equal.

This basically iterates through all the keys of `object1` and checks if the value corresponding to the key in `object1` is equal to the value in `object2`.

Comment: How would I use this inside _.filter?

Comment: @Casey Please edit the question and include all the information

Comment: This worked great!  I was able to modify it a bit to work inside _.filter().  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it looks like if the first item of object1 is found, then it won't check the second item.

Comment: @Casey JavaScript objects are HashMap implementations. So, if there are two items which are mapped to the same Hash value, then either of them will be overwritten by the other one.

Comment: Problem with this code is that if object2 has more properties than object1, comparing will not consider properties that are not object1 and will be true if his properties are equal. This is not valid response. 

Example:
Object1 = {a: 1, b:2},
Object2 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}

object1 === object2
Result:   true
Expected: false

Answer (score 12):

To Compare two objects using underscore.js

```
 **isEqual :** _.isEqual(object, other)
```

Performs an optimized deep comparison between the two objects, to determine if they should be considered equal.

Ex :

```
var stooge = {name: 'moe', luckyNumbers: [13, 27, 34]};
    var clone  = {name: 'moe', luckyNumbers: [13, 27, 34]};
     _.isEqual(stooge, clone)  
      Returns True
```

Comment: While `isEqual` is quite useful, it won't work if the other object has an additional property, like in OP's case.

Comment: It will also not work if the order of keys is not identical :/

Comment: @zero_cool order of keys shouldn't matter. JSON only orders arrays, not hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous function created simple consoling out function:

```
var compareMe = function (obj1, obj2, parentKey) {
  parentKey = parentKey || '';
  _.each(_.keys(obj1), function (key) {
    if(_.isObject(obj1[key]) ) {
        compareMe(obj1[key], obj2[key], parentKey + key + '.')
    } else {
        if (!_.has(obj2, key) || !_.isEqual(obj1[key], obj2[key])) {
            console.log(parentKey + key, obj1[key], obj2[key]);
        }
    }
  })
};
```

And call like:   compareMe(obj1, obj1)