# Best way to check if all property values in object are = ""

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to check if an object's properties have no value (e.g. obj.prop1=='' for all properties).

What is the best way to achieve this in an angular expression? Incidentally is the angular expression the best place to put this?

```
<i class="fa fa-filter" ng-class="{'white-icon':checkobjectpropertieshere)}"></i>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632281/using-underscore-js-to-compare-two-objects

Comment: not using underscore.js. Is this still relevant for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to loop and check, there's no default method:

```
function isEmptyObj(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if (obj[prop] != "") return false; //or some other checking 
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: trying this but it doesn't seem to trigger using ng-class

Comment: @darkace -- Did you make it a function on the `$scope`?

Comment: I just added the function to my controller. Although I just realised I should probably be calling it in ng-click, and storing the result as a var for ng-class. What are you suggesting with $scope?

Comment: If you want to call this from the view - it has to be defined like: `$scope.isEmptyObj = function(obj)` @darkace

Comment: I seem to be getting the syntax wrong somehow XD D:

Comment: Pop open the console, see any errors? How are you trying to use this in `ngClass`?

Comment: Ah I've got it working, the root of my problem was thinking it was an object within an object within the scope. This is now working great, however this is now running the function constantly. Don't know if there's a better way to implement this or get the looping to stop?

Comment: Since it's in the view, it'll run whenever the digest cycle runs. If you know when you need this ran, assign the result to a variable and use that in the `ngClass` expression.

Answer (score 1):

To check if object contains **any** falsy value. To check if value is empty string, use `return obj[e] === '';`

Use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var containsFalsy = Object.keys(obj).some(function (e) {
    return !obj[e];
});
```

---

To check if object contains **all** falsy values.

Use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
var containsFalsy = Object.keys(obj).every(function (e) {
    return !obj[e];
});
```