# How to compare and filter only unmatched arrays from two array of objects in es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In my Angular Application, I'm trying to get only the updated array which was modified from UI.

Here, I have two array where one of the role_name is changed. I wanted to compare and filter out the modified object and return only those modified arrays. (in this case, **role_name** values are modified)

I have tried filtering out with the help of ES6, but its not working.

Can someone help me where am I missing?

```js
var arr1 = [ {
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "ABC",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "1",
  "user_name" : "Rywan"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "DEF",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "2",
  "user_name" : "adecg"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "GHJ",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "3",
  "user_name" : "dde"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "RRT",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "4",
  "user_name" : "kumar"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "SFR",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "5",
  "user_name" : "SASI"
}
];

var arr2 = [ {
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "ABC",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "1",
  "user_name" : "Rywan"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "ROLE_CHANGED",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "2",
  "user_name" : "adecg"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "GHJ",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "3",
  "user_name" : "dde"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "RRT",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "4",
  "user_name" : "kumar"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "SFR",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "5",
  "user_name" : "SASI"
}
];

   let filteredData;
     filteredData = arr1.filter(function(o1){
      //filter out (!) items in arr2
       return arr2.some(function(o2){
           return o1.role_name !== o2.role_name;  
      });
   });
   
   console.log(filteredData);
```

output should be

```
[
{
      "num" : null,
      "role_name" : "ROLE_CHANGED",
      "profile" : "ff",
      "user" : "1234",
      "rn" : "2",
      "user_name" : "adecg"
    }
]
```

Comment: If the order of elements in both of the arrays is expected to be the same, you can just do the following:

`const filteredData = arr2.filter((item, index) => item.role_name !== arr1[index].role_name);`

Comment: you could use underscore library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632281/using-underscore-js-to-compare-two-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit different solution what we have already.

On `Object.keys()` using `filter()` we can also compare `role_name` properties based on arrays' indexes if the value has changed like `arr1[index].role_name !== arr2[index].role_name`. This will return all the indexes of the array where we have changed values. Then with `map()` generating a new array for those elements based on the found array keys.

So the solution would be:

```
Object.keys(arr1).filter(index => arr1[index].role_name !== arr2[index].role_name)
                 .map(index => arr2[index]);
```

`Object.keys()`:

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

`Array.prototype.filter()`:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

`Array.prototype.map()`:

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

I think you can try the following:

```js
const arr1 = [{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "ABC",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "1",
  "user_name" : "Rywan"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "DEF",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "2",
  "user_name" : "adecg"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "GHJ",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "3",
  "user_name" : "dde"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "RRT",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "4",
  "user_name" : "kumar"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "SFR",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "5",
  "user_name" : "SASI"
}];

const arr2 = [{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "ABC",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "1",
  "user_name" : "Rywan"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "ROLE_CHANGED",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "2",
  "user_name" : "adecg"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "GHJ",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "3",
  "user_name" : "dde"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "RRT",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "4",
  "user_name" : "kumar"
},
{
  "num" : null,
  "role_name" : "SFR",
  "profile" : "ff",
  "user" : "1234",
  "rn" : "5",
  "user_name" : "SASI"
}];

const changedObjects = Object.keys(arr1).filter(index => arr1[index].role_name !== arr2[index].role_name)
                                        .map(index => arr2[index]);
   
console.log(changedObjects);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

Your logic is a little flawed, because your `.some()` will always return true since there is always one element that will be different. What you want is to do actually check if any one of the role names **are identical**. When no matches are found (i.e. `.some()` returns false), then you know that role_name has been changed:

```
const filteredData = arr2.filter((o1, i) => {
  return !arr1.some((o2) => {
    return o1.role_name === o2.role_name;
  });
});
```

```js
var arr1 = [{
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "ABC",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "1",
    "user_name": "Rywan"
  },
  {
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "DEF",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "2",
    "user_name": "adecg"
  },
  {
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "GHJ",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "3",
    "user_name": "dde"
  },
  {
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "RRT",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "4",
    "user_name": "kumar"
  },
  {
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "SFR",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "5",
    "user_name": "SASI"
  }
];

var arr2 = [{
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "ABC",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "1",
    "user_name": "Rywan"
  },
  {
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "ROLE_CHANGED",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "2",
    "user_name": "adecg"
  },
  {
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "GHJ",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "3",
    "user_name": "dde"
  },
  {
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "RRT",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "4",
    "user_name": "kumar"
  },
  {
    "num": null,
    "role_name": "SFR",
    "profile": "ff",
    "user": "1234",
    "rn": "5",
    "user_name": "SASI"
  }
];

const filteredData = arr2.filter((o1, i) => {
  return !arr1.some((o2) => {
    return o1.role_name === o2.role_name;
  });
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: Great! My Logic is the issue